# Does Continuity in Weak Operator Topology imply Continuity in Strong Operator Topology?

Tags: banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

This homework problem has puzzled me for almost a year. As nobody in the class has figured it out, I would like to seek a proof or a disproof here.

**Problem (Prove or Disprove)** Let $X$ be a [Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space) and assume that $T\colon [0,\infty) \to \mathcal{L}(X, X)$ satisfies

1. $T(0)=I$,
2. $T(s+t)=T(s)T(t)$ for all $s,t\in[0,\infty)$,
3. For all $x\in X$ and $x^*\in X^*$ we have $x^*(T(t)x)\to x^*(x)$ as $t\to 0^+$.

Show that $T$ is a linear [$C_0$-semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup).

**Explanation** The third condition states that $T$-is continuous in the weak operator topology, while being a $C_0$-semigroup requires continuity in the strong operator topology.

**A Partial Result** We can prove for the case when $X$ is reflexive. Again, I want to stress that I am not sure if the statement in the problem is true. The proof for the partial result might be over-complicated. One might want to work on the problem him/herself before looking at our result.

The main idea comes from *A Short Course on Operator Semigroups* by <del>S. Axler and K.A. Ribet</del> Engel, Klaus-Jochen and Nagel, Rainer, while there are still some original ideas in the proof.

**A Technical Lemma** Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded right continuous function. Then $f$ has only countably discontinuous points.

We omit the proof the technical lemma. Back to prove the problem assuming $X$ is reflexive.

**Proof of partial result**

Let $E=\left\{x\in X\mid (T(h)-I)x\to 0\text{ strongly as }h\to 0^+\right\}$. Our goal is to prove $E=X$.

We have convergence of $T$ in weak operator topology at 0 and also have boundedness for sequences that are weakly convergent, so we can still obtain that $||T(t)||\leq Me^{\omega t}$ for all $t\geq 0$ and some $M\geq 1$, $\omega\geq 0$.

Also, we have right continuity in weak operator topology: for all $x\in X^*, x\in X$
$$\langle{x^*,T(t+h)x-T(t)x}\rangle=\langle{x^*,(T(h)-I)T(t)x}\rangle\to 0\text{ as }h\to 0^+.
$$

Now we define $L_r(x),x\in X, 0<r<1$ be such that for all $x^*\in X^*$
$$L_r(x)(x^*)=\frac{1}{r}\int_0^r\langle{x^*,T(s)x}\rangle ds.
$$
This Riemannian integral makes sense because the integrand is right continuous, and is ,by lemma, Riemannian integrable. It is clear that $L_r(x)$ is indeed linear. Note also $|{L_r(x)(x^*)}|\leq||{x^*}||\sup_{0<s<1}||{T(s)x}||$, so $L_r(x)$ is bounded, hence is well-defined.

What's more, since $X$ is reflexive, we can find $y_r(x)\in X$ such that $J_X(y_r(x))=L_r(x)$ and
$$\langle{x^*,y_r(x)}\rangle=\frac{1}{r}\int_0^r\langle{x^*,T(s)x}\rangle ds.(*)
$$

Then we compute that
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&||{(T(h)-I)y_r(x)}||=\sup_{||{x^*}||=1}\langle{x^*,(T(h)-I)y_r(x)}\rangle\\
&=&\sup_{||{x^*}||=1}\frac{1}{r}\left({\int_0^r\langle{x^*,T(s+h)x}\rangle ds-\int_0^r\langle{x^*,T(s)x}\rangle ds}\right)\\
&=&\sup_{||{x^*}||=1}\frac{1}{r}\left({\int_r^{r+h}\langle{x^*,T(s)x}\rangle ds-\int_0^h\langle{x^*,T(s)x}\rangle ds}\right)\\
&\leq&\sup_{||{x^*}||=1}\frac{2h}{r}||{x^*}||\sup_{0<s<1}||{T(s)}||\,||{x}||
\to 0\text{ as }h\to 0^+.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $D=\left\{y_r(x)\in X\mid x\in X, 0<r<1\right\}\subset E$. Clearly $y_r(x) \rightharpoonup x$ as $r\to 0^+$, so $D$ is weakly dense in $X$ and so is $E$, where "weakly dense in $X$" means its weak sequential closure is $X$. Note also $E$ is convex, therefore $E$ is strongly dense in $X$.

Finally, fix $\epsilon>0, x\in X$. There is $y\in E$ such that $||{x-y}||<\frac{\epsilon}{3+3Me^\omega}$. Choose $\delta\in(0,1)$ such that for all $0\leq h<\delta$, we have $||{T(h)y-y}||<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
||{T(h)x-x}||&\leq& ||{T(h)(x-y)}||+||{T(h)y-y}||+||{y-x}||<\epsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $E=X$. **Q.E.D.**

Comment: I am pretty sure this is true.  I may have seen a proof in *A Short Course on Operator Semigroups* by Engel and Nagel (is this perhaps the book you are talking about? I can't find reference to any books at all by Axler and Ribet together).  If not then it would have been in Pazy's book *Semigroups of linear operators and applications to partial differential equations*.  Whichever of those books it is, I think this theorem appears near the beginning.

Comment: @Nate, this is really reassuring. I will check those references you mentioned. However according to my memory, one of my classmates (back a year ago) checked some literatures and didn't find the statement. But we might have just missed it. Anyway, thanks! And I would greatly appreciate if you can help pinpoint the reference.

Comment: I found the result I was thinking of.  It is Theorem 1.6 of Engel and Nagel.  But I apparently misremembered: it is not the same statement you are trying to prove. It assumes the stronger hypothesis that $T(t)$ is weakly continuous at every $t$, not just at $t=0$.  (That is, for every $x \in X, x^* \in X^*$ we have that $t \mapsto x^*(T(t) x)$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.)  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: That's ok. My impression is that the literatures give related(but not exact the same) results. The fact that they probably give the best result they could have made me worried about the possibility that the statement might be false.

Comment: Pazy's book contains what appears to be your statement as Theorem 1.4 of Section 2.1.  Unfortunately neither a proof nor a reference appears to be given.  In the end notes Pazy mentions a result which is almost the same: the hypothesis is that $T(t)$ is weakly measurable on $(0,\infty)$ and weakly continuous at $t=0$.  The reference given for this is Chapter X of E. Hille and R. S. Phillips, *Functional analysis and semi-groups*.  Perhaps this will be helpful.

Comment: By the way, I would appreciate if you could clarify your reference to "A Short Course on Operator Semigroups by S. Axler and K.A. Ribet" which as far as I can tell does not exist.  Are you talking about the book of that title by Engel and Nagel, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, the authors should be Engel and Nagel and you are right about everything of that book.

Comment: Looking at Engel and Nagel, Theorem 1.6, the only additional step in the proof other than those given in the OP is that $\{T(t)x\colon t\le T\}$ is weakly compact (for some $T > 0$), which is implied by $T(t)$ being weakly continuous. Then, Krein's theorem (Lemma A.1) says that its closed convex hull is norm-compact implying that $y_r(x)$ (as defined in the OP) are in $X$, and not just its double dual. The rest of the proof follows as in the question. Here, we only have that $T(t)$ is right-continuous.

Comment: I mean weakly compact, not norm-compact above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof that $T$ is continuous in the strong operator topology. As noted in the question, for each $x\in X$, the map $t\mapsto T_tx$ is right-continuous under the weak topology, and norm-bounded on each bounded interval. To complete the proof given in the question for an arbitrary Banach space, we just require the following lemma.

> **Lemma**: Let $X$ be a Banach space, $a < b\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f\colon[a,b]\to X$ be weakly right-continuous and norm-bounded. Then, there is a (unique) $y\in X$ such that
>   $$
> x^*(y)=\int_a^b x^*(f(t))\,dt
> $$
>   for all $x^*\in X$.

We can write $y=\int_a^bf(t)\,dt$, which is the [Bochner integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral). Rather than defining $L_r$, we can define $y_r(x)\in X$ directly as $y_r(x)=\frac1r\int_0^rT_tx\,dt$,
which satisfies
$$
x^*(y_r(x))=\frac1r\int_0^r x^*(T_tx)\,dt
$$
for all $x^*\in X^*$.
So, the remainder of the proof given in the question follows through unchanged for arbitrary Banach spaces.

---

The main step in proving the lemma above is the *Pettis measurability theorem*. For a [measurable space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) $(E,\mathcal{E})$ and Banach space $X$, a function $f\colon E\to X$ is called *simple* if it is of the form $f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n1_{t\in E_k}x_k$ for $E_k\in\mathcal{E}$ and $x_k\in X$, and $f$ is said to be strongly $\mathcal{E}$-measurable if there is a sequence $\{f_n\colon n=1,2,\ldots\}$ of simple functions converging pointwise to $f$. A function $f\colon E\to X$ is *separably valued* if its image is contained in a separable subspace of $X$.

> **Theorem (Pettis)**: Let $(E,\mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space, $X$ a Banach space, and $f\colon E\to X$. The following are equivalent
>
> 1. $f$ is strongly $\mathcal{E}$-measurable.
> 2. $f$ is separably valued and $t\mapsto x^*(f(t))$ is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable for each $x^*\in X^*$.

A statement and proof of the Pettis measurability theorem in this form is given in [these notes](http://ocw.tudelft.nl/uploads/media/Lecture01_01.pdf). Then, for any finite measure $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal{E})$, any $f\colon E\to X$ which is norm-bounded and strongly measurable is also Bochner integrable, so the Bochner integral $y=\int f\,d\mu$ is well-defined and satisfies $x^*(y)=\int x^*(f)\,d\mu$ for all $x^*\in X^*$. Constructing the Bochner integral is straightforward. For a simple $f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n1_{t\in E_k}x_k$ the Bochner integral is $\int f\,d\mu=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(E_k)x_k$. For a strongly measurable and norm-bounded $f$, we choose a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ converging pointwise to $f$. If $f$ is bounded in norm by $K$ then we can assume that $f_n$ are norm-bounded by $K+1$ (replace $f_n(t)$ by $1_{\{\lVert f_n(t)\rVert\le K+1\}}f_n(t)$). Then it can be seen that $\int f_n\,d\mu$ is Cauchy in $X$, and we set $\int f\,d\mu$ to be its limit.

To prove the lemma then, applying the Pettis integrability theorem, it is enough to show that if $f\colon[a,b]\to X$ is weakly right-continuous then it is separably valued and weakly measurable with respect to the Borel sigma-algebra on $[0,1]$.

Measurability of $t\mapsto x^*(f(t))$ follows from the fact that it is right-continuous and that right-continuous real-valued functions are Borel measurabile. To show that it is separably valued, let $S$ be the union of $\{b\}$ and the rational numbers in $[a,b]$. Let $Y_0$ be the subspace spanned by $\{f(t)\colon t\in S\}$, and $Y$ be the norm-closure of $Y_0$ in $X$. Then, $Y$ is separable. Also, as $Y_0$ is a subspace (in particular, it is convex), $Y$ is also the weak closure of $Y_0$. Now, for any $t\in[a,b]$ there exists $t_n\in S$ with $t_n\downarrow t$ and, by weak right-continuity, we have $f(t_n)\to f(t)$ weakly, so $f(t)\in Y$. Hence, the image of $f$ is contained in $Y$, and $f$ is separably valued.

---

**Update**: A proof of the result is also given in [these notes](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~attal/Operator_Semigroups.pdf), and uses the Bochner integral in essentially the same way as in my answer.
The paper [*On semigroups of operators in locally convex spaces*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1969-0248561-2) relaxes the conditions further. We only need to assume that $X$ is a metrizable locally convex space and, then, if $T_t$ is strongly measurable over $t > 0$ (or, by Pettis' theorem, almost separably valued and weakly measurable) then it is strongly continuous over $t > 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see that the condition implies immediately that the $t\to T_tx$ is right-continuous. Note that the condition only says it is right-continuous at $0$.

Comment: @ZilinJ.: That's implied by the semigroup condition $T_{s+t}=T_sT_t$.$$\lim_{s\downarrow t}T_s=\lim_{s\downarrow t}T_{s-t}T_t=T_t,$$in the weak operator topology.

Comment: sorry I was being stupid. Let me check your answer. I think it is probably correct.